# Hide Mac desktop icons with fade effect?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

Is it possible to hide or unhide the desktop icons on a Mac with a fade effect?
This could be potentially done by placing a image of the wallpaper over the actual desktop, 
so that when the desktop is clicked, the icons would appear.

Could an approch like this be `sandboxed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach would be to create a borderless `NSWindow` with an appropriate `level`. `kCGDesktopIconWindowLevelKey` is the level of the desktop icons, so that should work.

Sandboxing is not a problem for this because you don't actually remove the desktop icons, you just display a window on top of them.

You'll probably also want to set the `collectionBehavior` of the window to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary`, so that it's not affected by Exposé.

Comment: WOW there's even a Variable for the Icon Level ? That's great ! Thanks a lot for your answer ! So it is indeed possible :D
As you seem very experienced, omz, could you maybe also tell me if it would be possible to hide the icons again when the user double-clicks the desktop ( not the icons ). Really appreciate your help here!

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that. It might be possible to detect clicks on the desktop using `[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask...]`, but you couldn't distinguish clicks on the background from clicks on the icons...

Comment: Thanks anyways. Would have been great if it could have worked that way, but maybe I should just do something like hot corners.

Comment: One Last Question: Is it possible to fade the overlay when the user drags a file on the desktop (on drag event ?).
E.g.: The user wants to drag a file to the desktop, and while he hovers over the desktop, the icons fade in.

Comment: Well, to show the desktop icons when a drag enters your overlay windows, you'd just have to handle the "drag entered" event in your window/view. The hard part would be to hide the icons again when the drag'n'drop operation ends. I'm not sure if that's possible at all.

Comment: Mh.. if there's a "drag enter" event, shouldn't be there also a "drag leave" or "drag cancel" event so we can see when the drag stops ?
BTW: I had some ideas for double-click solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442265/register-double-click-on-desktop-but-not-on-icons

Comment: Well, yes, but the plan is (if I understood you correctly) to remove your drag target (so that the actual Desktop gets the drop), you won't get that event...

Comment: Yes, you're right. But maybe when "on drag enter" I could just fade the front fake "wallpaper layer" to opacity 0, so it is still there to receive the drag cancel or leave. Though the other question is then off course "how to make the item appear on the desktop at the correct position where the mouse dropped it ?" .. mh .. maybe "on fake layer drop" "get mouse x y position" and a "copy file to desktop x y position". Okay.. this is very experimental I must admit ..

Comment: As far as I know, there's no public API to put stuff at a specific location on the desktop. There's also the problem of sandboxing which might prevent you from accessing the desktop folder at all...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible, because:

1. The overlay would have to be over the desktop, but under new windows
2. This would most likely not be able to be sandboxed

But if you could it to work, the workflow would be along the lines of:

1. User clicks button (preferably menubar, as this app doesn't really have a window)
2. A full screen window (with UI elements disabled, such as menubar) fades in with the background image set as the Mac's background image
3. Clicking the button again would hide the window

Comment: Mh .. how's about hiding/unhiding icons on the desktop with the same (on click) system, but without an image overlay for the fade. So they just appear.
Would it be possible to make them appear on click on the desktop, while still retaining to the sandboxed guidelines ?

Comment: I do not believe you will be able to sandbox this, as it's going to need to modify key OSX elements. Here's a link, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW1

Comment: Yeah, I knew that page. Although there are other AppStore Apps that can hide the icons. So, you think only the action "click-desktop-to-show" would be un-sandboxable ?

Comment: What's an example of one of these apps?